# How to insert python variable into sql table

Tags: python, sql

I want to insert into SQL table python variables but just one of them with "select from other table" and the others with VALUES()

I want to write it in 1 line!

SQL-variables: strname,woort,wann,Uhrzeit

```
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wowann(Film) select FilmID from filme where filme.Name=%s",(strname,))
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wowann(Ort,Tag,Uhrzeit) VALUES(%s,%s,%s) ", (woort,wann,Uhrzeit)) 
db_connection.commit()
```

Comment: INSERT INTO wowann (...) select FilmID, param, param, param from ...

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the following code:**

```
db_cursor.execute("""
   INSERT INTO wowann(Film,Ort,Tag,Uhrzeit) SELECT FilmID,%s,%s,%s FROM filme WHERE filme.Name=%s;
   """ % ('woort','wann','Uhrzeit',strname)).fetchall()

db_connection.commit()
```